# Electron js desktop app: on disconnect the internet make the app onfocus or active window on the screen

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-packager

I have a desktop App built with Electron JS. I got `disconnectInternet()` function when the laptop is disconnected from wifi/internet the disconnectInternet function will be called and it will shows the notification and I want to make the application onFocus/active window on the desktop screen the moment it disconnect from internet.  How can I do this?
*and the electron version is "electron": "3.0.0"*
**main.js**

```
  function createWindow () {
   const win = new BrowserWindow({
   width: 800,
   height: 600
   })

   win.loadFile('index.html')
 }
```

---

**render.js**

```
function disconnectInternet(onDisconnected, timeout = 2000, withoutPass = false) {

  uiStatus.innerText = "disconnecting...";
  showNotification();
  // window.onfocus();   <-- also tried window.focus(), window.isFocused(true)
  // window.onshow();    <-- tried window.show()
  ...
  ...
 }
```

Comment: There are a few issues with your question: 1) You seem to confuse event listeners (functions starting with "on") with methods you can actually call. 2) What is `win`? What is `window`? You can only modify Electron's windows from within the main process. Please [edit] your question and include **all** code necessary to reproduce your problem -- please also see [mcve]. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner   if i'm not mistaken  win or window is not a keyword its just a variable which we can assign and  modify anywhere . 

const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const win = new BrowserWindow()

Comment: That still isn't an MCVE. Please [edit] your question according to the link I provided you with. Also, `window` *is* reserved in the render process, as it's the default window object you can use in normal web applications; it's `undefined` in the main process. If your `render.js` actually runs in the renderer process, `win` will not be defined there unless fetched from the main process. Do you use `remote`? Also, what is your concrete question? Can you already detect whether the computer is disconnected or do you want this answered as well?

Comment: Okay going to edit my question again. just double checked it you're right the win will be undefined in the main process. i'm using `ipc` instead of `remote` and yes i can detect whenever the computer is disconnected. i just want a sample that shows how to make the window onfocus or active on the screen when a particular function call(which here i got `disconnectInternet()` )